# Need a good approach for hosting ASP.NET MVC files in subfolder within an ASP.NET Web Forms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 web forms app and need to host an ASP.NET MVC app within the same web (i.e. within the same IIS process - same session, modules, etc.)

This works pretty easily as long as the folder/files from both are located in the root folder.

How can I cleanly allow the MVC files to be all contained within a subfolder?

I have a view engine that adds the location formats for the sub-folder.  This allows all the controller/view stuff to work fine, but I need a good solution for content files.  Currently, I have to be careful to ensure that all the paths in the MVC app to point to the MVC subfolder name, as in:

```
Url.Content("~/mvc/Content/Site.css")
```

What are some solid options for accomplishing this?

I don't want any requests going to or from Web Forms to be affected.  This logic should only manipulate URLs that can be resolved within the MVC engine (or manipulate all URLs *except* URLs that can be resolved by the Web Forms engine alone)

**Edit:**  It is a customer requirement that both sites share the same IIS Session, so a separate application is off the table for now.  Not interested in sharing session between IIS processes at this point.

Comment: Can you create a sub application within the IIS site? (IIS Site > Add Application)

Comment: Why dont the standard folders work? MVC views and controllers typically go into a `~/Views/` folder, and any supporting files such as CSS and JS can be placed in other folders and referenced as appropriate.

Comment: I want to keep the site's MVC-related folders/files separate because this project involves a long migration path at the end of which the web-forms site will go away entirely.
This question is part of an attempt to limit the changes to the existing site as well as limit the restructure/organization necessary to decommission the web forms site.

Comment: @jorgebg, it is a customer requirement that both sites share the same IIS Session, so a separate application makes this more difficult to implement/maintain reliably.

Comment: @heiserman: You can integrate the MVC project inside a WebForms project http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx I'm doing the same in some projects and works great as you can reuse some resources (CSS, images)

Comment: @EduardoMolteni That's what I am doing, for the most part.  What I'm looking for is a clean way to keep the web forms and mvc files in separate folders.

Comment: @heiserman: I put all things MVC related under the `Views` folder. Each view with the related controller in their own folder. The controller with a different namespace obviously. The models and the images are shared. Works like a charm.

Comment: "I have a view engine that adds the location formats for the sub-folder." => how do you do this? would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just make a set of URL helper extensions that would take this into account for me.

**The Extension Class**

```
namespace Core.Extensions{
   public static class UrlHelperExtensions
   {
      public static string Image(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
      {
        return helper.Content("~/mvc/Content/Images/" + fileName);
      }

      public static string Stylesheet(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
      {
        return helper.Content("~/mvc/Content/Css/" + fileName);
      }

      public static string Script(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
      {
        return helper.Content("~/mvc/Content/Scripts/" + fileName);
      }
   }
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Core.Extensions" />  <-- Add your extension namespace here
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

**Usage in Views**

```
<link href="@Url.Stylesheet("site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Script("jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<img src="@Url.Image("MyImageName.jpg")" />

<!--CSS in a sub directory from your root that you specified in your Extension class -->
<link href="@Url.Stylesheet("SomeDirectory/otherCss.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One workable solution is to create a sub-domain for the MVC application, ex. mvc.mydomain.com. It provides a clear separation between the applications that are easily integrated, and does not require an additional domain.